Issue with MSVC compiler in QT
I am not able to use MSVC COMPILER in qt i am also getting CMake kit configuration issue so i have separately installed CMake and added the path in qt which is CMake-D i have installed visual studio 2019 i am not able still use MSVC Compiler.I have attached snaps
Am i missing any step.MSVC issue
CMake path
Kit config CMake errors

What does your CMakeLists.txt look like?

This is definitely weird since you have your own CMake version installed.
If you run your CMake-D cmake.exe --version from a terminal, does it run correctly?
If so, please check with your Antivirus program. I don't see any other reason why Qt Creator wouldn't be able to start executables.
Otherwise you could get some logging for Qt Creator.
Either from Qt Creator itself via Tools > Debug Qt Creator > Show Logs... or by setting the environment variable QT_LOGGING_RULES=qtc*=true before starting qtcreator (on Windows you need something like DebugView to view the output).
